# How can I have a root level AppSync/Apollo client when the user isn't necessarily authenticated?

Tags: reactjs, redux, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

For background I'm using react, redux, react-router(v4), react-cognito, and appsync. My application uses [PrivateRoute](https://gist.github.com/rcanepa/b4ce0dff8d85b357504e04b03e69ac66) to ensure the user has authorization for each route requested. react-cognito handles all the authentication for me and stores JWT tokens, Federated Identity temporary IAM access key / secret access key / session token in the redux store.

The AppSync tutorial assumes you are using AWS-amplify instead of react-cognito, and places the `<ApolloProvider client = {this.client}>` at root application level, where

```
this.client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
      url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
      region: AppSync.region,
      auth: {

        // Amazon Cognito Federated Identities using AWS Amplify
        //credentials: () => Auth.currentCredentials(),

        // Amazon Cognito user pools using AWS Amplify
        // type: AUTH_TYPE.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS,
        // jwtToken: async () => (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
      },
      disableOffline: true
    });
  }
```

In my case, at root component mounting there is nothing in the store yet from react-cognito (half my SPA is public requiring no authentication) and I'm not sure what async function could be called at mount to pull this once available as seems to be done in the example above.

For the time being I've solved this by putting ApolloProvider at the component level, only for components that need it and that exist in PrivateRoutes (hence will have credential info available in the store), but this leads to code duplication and feels wrong.

Short of migrating to aws-amplify, any suggestions how to refactor this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep using the `ApolloProvider` at the root component level. The auth config will be read only when needed before making the request to the AppSync API.

Some more detail:

The object under the `auth` key in the config that you pass to the AWSAppSyncClient constructor can contain different values depending on the authentication type that your API is using.

- `apiKey` for `API_KEY`
- `credentials` for `AWS_IAM`
- `jwtToken` for `AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS`

These three keys can contain values **or functions that return a promise** that will resolve with the value. The AWSAppSyncClient will get the value (or await for the promise) on **every request**.

It doesn't matter if at instantiation time the info is not yet in the redux-store. I haven't tested this (also, I am not familiar with react-cognito), but it would be something like this:

```
this.client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    url: AppSync.graphqlEndpoint,
    region: AppSync.region,
    auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.AWS_IAM,
        credentials: async () => {
            const state = store.getState();

            return state.cognito.creds;
        }
    },
    disableOffline: true
});
```